# Error when starting script : No such file or directory while executing a shell script

Tags: unix

I've just encountered same issue as described at http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/84684-getting-no-such-file-directory-while-executing-shell-script.html

Question by user : "I am getting : No such file or directory while executing a shell script. But i have that corresponding file in the corresponding path. It also have executable rights. "

Answer : "Have you start your script with /directory/scriptname or ./scriptname?"

This worked for, once I started the script using "./scriptname". I started this script on multiple servers and on some machines I could just use "scriptname" and on others I needed to use "./scriptname" Why is "./" required on some machines but not on others? On all machines the file permissions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current directory (`.`) is in the `PATH`, you can run a script both ways:

```
script.sh        # Shell will look for the script.sh in
                 # every directory listed in $PATH

./script.sh      # Shell will invoke the script.sh located
                 # in the current directory.
```

If the current directory is not in the `PATH`, you have to run it like this:

```
./script.sh
```

That's because shell will have no idea where to find this script - it's parent folder is not in the `PATH`. Invoking it with `./` tells shell where to find it.

To add the current directory to the `PATH`, issue the following command:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:.
```

The list is colon delimeted, co the above means "new path will be the same as the old path with the addition of the current directory (`.`)".

**Edit:** Note the @Cyrille comment - putting `.` in the `PATH` may not be a good idea (for security reasons).

Comment: It is also bad practice to put a `.` in the `$PATH` ([security reasons](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/22806-why-bad-idea-insert-dot-path.html)). You can however put your script in a defined directory and add this directory to your `$PATH`